# Strange behaviour when serializing Contacts.Contact on Win 10 Mobile with JSON.NET

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

In the code-behind page in a UWP App, I am serializing an object of type `Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact` and sending the results in a ValueSet object back to an another app using the method `ProtocolForResultsOperation.ReportCompleted(ValueSet)` (the app is launched originally be an another one).

Here is the code:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            var protocolForResultsArgs = e.Parameter as ProtocolForResultsActivatedEventArgs;
            if (protocolForResultsArgs != null)
            {
                var contactPicker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
                Contact contact = await contactPicker.PickContactAsync();
                if (contact != null)
                {
                    string c = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact);
                    ValueSet result = new ValueSet();
                    result.Add("ContactTaken", c);
                    protocolForResultsArgs.ProtocolForResultsOperation.ReportCompleted(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    ValueSet result = new ValueSet();
                    result.Add("ContactTaken", "No contact selected");
                    protocolForResultsArgs.ProtocolForResultsOperation.ReportCompleted(result);
                }
            }
        }
```

It works on PC unproblematic. But when I run it on a mobile device with Windows 10 Mobile (Lumia 640), it crashes!

And it crashes even if I return something other than the serialized JSON string, i.e. it crashes as follows as well:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            var protocolForResultsArgs = e.Parameter as ProtocolForResultsActivatedEventArgs;
            if (protocolForResultsArgs != null)
            {
                var contactPicker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
                Contact contact = await contactPicker.PickContactAsync();
                if (contact != null)
                {
                    string c = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact);
                    ValueSet result = new ValueSet();
                    result.Add("ContactTaken", "hello world");
                    protocolForResultsArgs.ProtocolForResultsOperation.ReportCompleted(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    ValueSet result = new ValueSet();
                    result.Add("ContactTaken", "No contact selected");
                    protocolForResultsArgs.ProtocolForResultsOperation.ReportCompleted(result);
                }
            }
        }
```

Therefore, I thought, it may-be cannot serialize the given object for some reason. So I tried to show the results of the serialization in the app before giving them back to the caller app, i.e. as follows:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            var protocolForResultsArgs = e.Parameter as ProtocolForResultsActivatedEventArgs;
            if (protocolForResultsArgs != null)
            {
                var contactPicker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
                Contact contact = await contactPicker.PickContactAsync();
                if (contact != null)
                {
                    string c = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact);
                    textBlock.text = c;
                }
                else
                {
                    ValueSet result = new ValueSet();
                    result.Add("ContactTaken", "No contact selected");
                    protocolForResultsArgs.ProtocolForResultsOperation.ReportCompleted(result);
                }
            }
        }
```

The serialized text appears correctly!!

Any explanation please?

Comment: Yes, it should input value to .ctor

Comment: Sorry? What do you mean exactly please?

Comment: Hi, I tried to test your code, it works fine, but instead of using `Json.NET`, I use `Newtonsoft.Json`, you can try to serialize it with this nuget package. In addition, my software minimum platform is 14393, the target platform is 15063, and the test device is Lumia 950 (OS Build: 15254).

Comment: Yes I mean `Newtonsoft.Json`, they are the same, i.e. `Json.NET` has become `Newtonsoft.Json`. Did you try to launch the app by an another one and give the serialized JSON back or did you only try the serialization inside the app?

Comment: Yes, I created two apps, one app wakes up another app via `Launcher.LaunchUriForResultsAsync()` and receives the json data passed from another app (read contacts), you can provide the system version of your test device Details?

Comment: It still does not work by me. I am testing on 10.0.15063.1868

Comment: Hi, please check if the contact information is complete. Based on the code you currently provide, we have not detected any obvious anomalies. In order to reproduce your problem, I hope you can provide the complete project file. In addition, you can listen to the `UnhandledException` event in `App.xaml.cs`, which is helpful if we can know the crash exception information.